# How to make rsync delete files in the destination folder that has been deleted in the source with shell glob?

Tags: sync, rsync, delete

I'm trying to collect files periodically from multiple sources into a single file dest.
To save copies I tried using rsync but I have a bit of a trouble.
Let's say I want to copy some files from folders:

```
"/var/log/dir2/*.cert",
"/var/log/dir1",
```

The thing is, lets say /var/log/dir2 contain 2 cert files (file1, file2). I sync them once:

```
 rsync -av /var/log/dir2/*.cert  /tmp/dest --delete-before
```

Great, now dest contain file1.cert and file2.cert
now:

```
rm /var/log/dir2/file1.cert
```

sync again:

```
rsync -av /var/log/dir2/*.cert  /tmp/dest --delete-before
```

I would expect dest to contain only file2.cert, that is file1.cert to be deleted just like in the source dir but it doesn't happen.. why is that? How can I make it work?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. You deleted `file1.cert` in the source direcory, so `*.cert` will never be evaluated to `file1.cert`. Therefor only `file2.cert` will be synced and `file1.cert` remains untouched in the destination.

Answer (score 0):

the delete-before should work where you are sync'ing folders, rather than individual files.

if you tried:

```
rsync -av /var/log/dir2/  /tmp/dest --delete-before
```

I would suspect that this would work the way you intend.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to sync all files in dir2, only those that with the ext ".cert" for example

Comment: you might be better off including an "--include" requirement then.
e.g. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-exclude-files-and-directories-with-rsync/
```
rsync -a -m --include='*.jpg' --include='*/' --exclude='*' src_directory/ dst_directory/
```